# Why don't new line characters appear in the textbox when I use textBox1.AppendText

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make some kind of a terminal application using ssh.net libray in c#. I have been succesful to send commands and recieve output but when I append the the output to textbox new line characters disappear although I can see them in message box. How can I fix this problem?

```
SshCommand sc = client.CreateCommand(command);
sc.Execute();
textBox1.AppendText(command);
textBox1.AppendText("\n");
string answer = sc.Result;
textBox1.AppendText(answer);
MessageBox.Show(sc.Result);
textBox1.AppendText("\n");
textBox2.Clear();
```

When I run ls command, I get the output as:

[image: When I run ls command, I get the output as:]

Comment: Is textbox multiline or single line ?

Comment: It is multiline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `TextBox` which doesn't work with `\n`, it needs `\r\n` as a new line.

You can use `RichTextBox` which works with only a `\n` as newline.

Comment: Replacing "\n" with "\r\n" in the answer string solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: But then how does textBox1.AppendText("\n"); work nd actually print a new line

Comment: @GizemY I don't know. That's a mystery on it's own.